# docker-compose context with remote ssh doens't work

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created a minimal docker-compose.yml file, something like this

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  odoo:
    image: odoo:14.0
    container_name: odoo-app
    restart: always
    command:
      --without-demo all
```

then create a new docker context using

```
sudo docker context create remote --docker "host=ssh://root@my-remote.server.com:2222"
```

i can see the new created context using

```
sudo docker context ls
```

i can connect to ssh without problem

When i try to run this deployment nothing happen

```
(venv) augusto@augusto-NUC10i7FNH:~/Progetti/odoo$ sudo docker-compose --verbose --context remote -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml,./docker-compose.prod.yml
(venv) augusto@augusto-NUC10i7FNH:~/Progetti/odoo$
```

why?

Both hosts (local and remote server) have Ubuntu 20.04 and the same version of docker-compose

```
docker-compose version 1.28.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 4.4.1
CPython version: 3.8.5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

Comment: Wich version works? I get the last version :/

Comment: I use that sintax as specified in my answer above.. sudo docker-compose --verbose --context remote -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d

Comment: Yeah, I removed the previous comments because they weren't helpful. Sorry about that. I can't reproduce the behavior you've described -- with both an `ssh://` context and a `tcp://` context, `docker-compose` seems to work correctly using the `--context` argument.

Comment: ok i managed to solve, there was problems with ssh key. thanks for help!